# Mysql distance function

Tags: mysql, distance

I have the problems with my function which needs to calculate distance between given coordinates. As I can see problem is with negative values, and I am running out of ideas how to solve this, so if someone can help me I will really appreciate it!

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`sfff_user`@`%` FUNCTION `GetUserDistance`(lat VARCHAR (20), lon VARCHAR (20), userLat VARCHAR (20), userLon VARCHAR (20)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE distance INT (11);

    IF ISNULL(lat) OR ISNULL(lon) OR lat = '' OR lon = '' THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        SELECT
            3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((lat - ABS(userLat)) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(ABS(userLat) * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((lon - userLon) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))
        INTO
            distance;

        RETURN distance;
    END IF;

END
```

For example result for this call:

`select GetUserDistance(44, 21, 44, 21) as distance;` is **0** which is ok

But look at this:

```
select GetUserDistance('-15.4167', '28.2833', '-15.4167', '28.2833') as distance;
```

is **2129** which is insane!

So if you can take a look it would be verry nice to have correct function, since I am dying to solve this :(

Thanks.

Comment: If you afford it, use [PostGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS) as it has a lot of such functions already build in.

Comment: Isn't this a problem with ABS(userLat) ? Just replacing it with userLat would solve your issue I guess.

Comment: @Scharron, nope it will not I tired, feeela - unfortenately not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For safe side you should CAST `VARCHAR` to `DECIMAL` and as @Scharron said no need of `ABS` try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetUserDistance`(arg_lat VARCHAR (20), arg_lon VARCHAR (20), arg_userLat VARCHAR (20), arg_userLon VARCHAR (20)) RETURNS int(11) NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE distance INT (11);
    DECLARE lat, lon, userLat, userLon DECIMAL(14,4);

    SET lat = CAST(arg_lat AS DECIMAL(14,4));
    SET lon = CAST(arg_lon AS DECIMAL(14,4));
    SET userLat = CAST(arg_userLat AS DECIMAL(14,4));
    SET userLon = CAST(arg_userLon AS DECIMAL(14,4));

    IF ISNULL(lat) OR ISNULL(lon) OR lat = '' OR lon = '' THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        SELECT
            3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((lat - userLat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(ABS(userLat) * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((lon - userLon) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))
        INTO
            distance;

        RETURN distance;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/2/Geo%2520Distance%2520Search%2520with%2520MySQL%2520Presentation.ppt&ei=SU0aUNTaO4Oo9gSFwYCoCw&usg=AFQjCNF-JRRwbrOhQPim3d1wRDc2dI8HsQ&sig2=J1Zj0oIenjauLCNeJGRkqw), the formula should be without `ABS`:

```
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((lat - userLat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(ABS(userLat) * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((lon - userLon) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))
```